# Does the Taylor series of $\ln (1-x)$ converge uniformly on $[0, 1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

We know that:

$$\ln (1-x) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$$

Does the Taylor series converge uniformly on $[0, 1)$?
I guess the answer is yes. What I have tried to do is that, after I showed pointwise convergence ,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{x^n}{n} = \sum_{n=N+2}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$$

but I am unable to bound the last series. Any help to continue?

**Edit:** If it does not converge uniformly, how would one explain that  $$\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}\, {\rm d}x= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{n}\, {\rm d}x$$

Comment: About your last question: uniform convergence is a sufficient condition, not a necessary one.

Comment: Yes I know that. If that converges uniformly , then the interchange is immediate. If not, I guess i'll have to go another way. But I do not remember the tests by heart.

Comment: Uniformly convergent series are uniformly Cauchy. But, for $M\gg N$, what is $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1^-} \sum\limits_{n=N}^M {x^n \over n}$?

Comment: @DavidMitra That clarifies that a bit. I think the limit is $+\infty$

Comment: The interchange of summation and integration is immediately justified by the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you very much for that. I thought as much, but I did not remember the hypotheses of that theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question:

> Let $S$ any set, let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a sequence of bounded functions (i.e. $\forall n,\, \sup_{x\in S}|f_n(x)|<+\infty$) converging uniformly on $S$ to a function $f$. Then $f$ is bounded as well.

So, the partial sums cannot converge uniformly on $[0,1)$ to $\ln(1-x)$, because $\lim_{x\to 1^-}|\ln(1-x)|=+\infty$

Comment: Τhank you. Therefore the Taylor cannot converge. How about the second question?

Comment: I'm thinking about it. I'd say Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, but I presume you meant to integrate with the Riemann integral instead of Lebesgue... @Tolaso

Comment: @Talaso You have uniform convergence on $[0,1-\epsilon]$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Hence the equation with $\int_0^{1-\epsilon}$ follows. To show that the limits can be interchanged without the simple reason of uniform convergence, note that "everything" is positive. Or note that $\int_{1-\epsilon}^1$ is sufficiently small

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not converge uniformely on whole interval. But on every compact subset it does.
$$ \forall \varepsilon > 0\; x \in <0, 1 - \varepsilon>: \ln(1 - x) \rightrightarrows T[\ln(1-x)](x) $$